# Magento 2 Convert backend admin grid to use joint table

Tags: module, grid, magento2.2.3, join-table, custom-grid

What are the step I need to take to convert my backend admin grid to use a joint table I have my grid example with column `id` and `name`

`id` comes from the `mainTable` and `name` from the secondtable:
[image]

I have added to my collection:

```
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('second_table')], //2nd table name by which you want to join
        'main_table.entity_id = secondTable.main_table_entity_id', // common column which available in both table 
        '*' // '*' define that you want all column of 2nd table. if you want some particular column then you can define as ['column1','column2']
    );
```

This works well on the Frontend but not sure what I am missing to make it work on the admin grid?

Answer (score 0):

You may did not add the custom column from 2nd tables in you modules Adminhtml layout XML files.

we assumed your custom extension name is Company_MyModule.

**step 1:**
Assumed your admin grid XML file location is: ***Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/ui/customer_listing.xml***

You can edit the customer_listing.xml file as below.

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
         <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">

        <column name="custom_id">
           -----------
        </column>  
        <column name="name" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**step 2:**
Assumed you collection model File location is: ***Company\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\MyModule\collection.php***

you can edit the collection model With below code

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
     $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('second_table')], 
        'main_table.entity_id = secondTable.main_table_entity_id', 
        '*' 
    );
    return $this;
}
```

step 3: Please run following CLI command from you Magento root directory

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/admingtml/*
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

You can check this link [How to Join custom table to customer grid collection and show new column in Grid in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186074/how-to-join-custom-table-to-customer-grid-collection-and-show-new-column-in-grid?rq=1)

Comment: I've tried your link now It doesn't even loop the data it returns `We couldn't find any records` !